# Is there a PDFSmartCopy for PDF/A

Tags: java, itext

I have to handle both format, but customer ask me to improve all the possibile soulitions to reduce files size. PdfSmartCopy is the best way I found for standard PDF, but I it's unusable for PDF/A becouse if I try to copy a PDF/A with that, output isn't a PDF/A, but just a standard PDF.

Are there solutions like the PdfSmartCopy for PDF/A ?

TY

Comment: No, so far, we've only implemented [PdfACopy](http://api.itextpdf.com/pdfa/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfACopy.html), which is a version of [PdfCopy](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfCopy.html) that preserves PDF/A compliance when merging PDF/A documents. We didn't implement such a version for [PdfSmartCopy](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfSmartCopy.html) yet. A large part of our development is customer-driven and so far we didn't have any customers asking for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is, but with iText 5.5.7 or greater. It's `PdfASmartCopy`. The release notes are here: http://itextpdf.com/release/iText557